# Quartz job error: Job class must implement the Job interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, urlclassloader

I have a spring boot application that uses a custom classloader to load jars from an external library at runtime and then creates Quartz Jobs.  The classloader is taking all the urls from  the context classloader and then adding in the external jars.  When logging all of the files from the classloader I can see that all required jars are there.  I have found some other post that reference this being a classloader issue, but I'm not sure what I can do differently.  Here is the code i'm using:

```
        loader = myLoader.getMyLoader(branchName);

        log.info("POST LOAD EXTERNAL JARS");
        for (URL url : loader.getURLs()) {
            log.info(url.getFile());
        }

        Class<? extends Job> myClass = (Class<? extends Job>) loader.loadClass(module.getClassnamelong()).newInstance().getClass();
        log.info("module class created: " + myClass.getName());

        jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(myClass).setJobData(getJobDataMapFrom(module, instance)).withIdentity(jobName, module.getModulename()).build();
```

The failure is occurring in JobBuilder.newJob().  The classes that i'm loading all extend a base abstract class that implements Job.

I have found that if I package the external jars into my spring boot application they work just fine skipping the runtime classloading.  My goal is for these to be plugins, so to speak, that we can modify without redeploying the entire application.

Comment: If your `loader` is a different `ClassLoader` then the classloader of Quartz then even if your object implements `Job` it still is a different class `Job`. Classloading can be confusing at times.

Comment: Do you have suggestions on how i get a handle to that so that I can ensure they use the same?

Comment: Can you explain where your loader positioned in the class loader hierarchy?